# Не работает bumblebee. И optirun

Tags: fedora, nvidia

ОС: Fedora 30.
При проверке устройств такой вывод:

```
[kokos@localhost ~]$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3822
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208BM [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3822
        Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

При попытке запустить optirun выдается ошибка:

```
[kokos@localhost ~]$ optirun firefox
[ 4179.346209] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 4179.346391] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Боюсь накосячить, поэтому решил спросить в чем может быть проблема?
Нужно ли выключать nouveau? Подскажите что же делать.

Comment: Изучали https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee_(Русский)?

Comment: Я устанавливал вот по этой инструкции для ноутбуков: https://www.easycoding.org/2017/01/11/pravilnaya-ustanovka-drajverov-nvidia-v-fedora.html